# Extracting data from JSON object containing arrays

Tags: json, node.js, api, npm, https

I am trying to extract the data from the response body from a server. I have browsed the internet for a while and found a few things that "should" work but don't. The request is a https request that is returning a JSON object.

```
//Open the request:
request({

  //Set the request Method:
  method: 'POST',
  //Set the headers:
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': "Bearer "+ token,
    'X-Originating-Ip': ipAddress
  },
  //Set the URL:
  url: 'URL',
  //Set the request body:
  body: { 'Body here'},
  }, function(error, response, body){

    //Alert the response body:
    for(var i=0; body.data.listings.length; i++){
      console.log(data.listings[i].listingType);
    }
    console.log(response.statusCode);
  });
```

For security reasons I cannot show the actual response body but it is a JSON object that contains multiple arrays.

Answer (score 0):

probably you should `console.log(body.data.listing[i].listingType)`

Another good practice to fix the error would be:

```
body.data.listings.forEach(function(element,index){
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the for loop

```
for(var i=0; body.data.listings.length; i++){
  console.log(data.listings[i].listingType);
}
```

Firstly, the terminating condition of the loop is `body.data.listings.length` which will always return the length of the `listings` and is always truthy for a non-empty array. You need to change the loop declaration to

```
for(var i=0; i<body.data.listings.length; i++){
```

It should correctly traverse all the items in the array.
Secondly, as James mentioned, you should use `body.data.listings[i].listingType` rather than `data.listings[i].listingType` inside the loop.

Comment: I am still getting a TypeError: Cannot read property 'listings' of undefined

Comment: @ChristopherLittlewood That means `body` object does not have a `data` property. Try to debug by printing with `console.log(JSON.stringify(body))`